# How to run deployed app in Docker for Windows?

Tags: asp.net, docker

Based on this [article](http://fluentbytes.com/deploying-asp-net-4-5-to-docker-on-windows/) I was trying to deploy ASP.NET 4.5 application using Docker for Windows.

I have done everthing and I have checked container IP using `docker inspect Container_ID`.
I've put this IP to my browser and it opens only default IIS page.

So it seems that IIS server works, but how am I suppouse to open my application?

http://172.30.169.6 and http://172.30.169.6:80 - both of them displaying default IIS site.

[image]

Comment: I'll verify the answer tomorrow :) Too busy now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deploy an ASP.NET web application to a Docker container you can use the following procedure.

### Publish Preset

Create a publish preset using the `File System` publish method. The resulting `.pubxml` file should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Websites\DockerDeploy\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

### Docker Image

Pull the official ASP.NET image from Microsoft:

```
docker pull microsoft/aspnet
```

### Dockerfile

Since the publish profile from above writes the application to `C:\Websites\DockerDeploy\`, the `dockerfile` must be saved under `C:\Websites\`.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
COPY ./DockerDeploy/ /inetpub/wwwroot/
```

### Custom Image

```
docker build -t mywebapplication .
```

### Run the Container

```
docker run -p 80:80 mywebapplication
```

[image: Web application]

Comment: Well I cannot find `.pubxml` using publish `File System`

Comment: This file is automatically generated by VS and holds the configuration of your publish profile. I have only put it there to provide an overview of the exact settings I used for publishing.

Comment: Actually I couldn't find this file, but it seems that is not necessery anyway. But it works, thank you ;)

Comment: If you get the 'cannot access the file because its being used by another process' error when running: docker run -p 80:80 mywebapplication then use a new port number like this: docker run -p 5000:80 mywebapplication and then load the page via 127.0.0.1:5000/index.html where index.html is your default page name. this worked for me.